# Able to see the full size of a list, but ListView not showing data

Tags: android

im getting error

> string resource id #0x3

listSongYear return the full length but it is not placing it in listview

```
 if (listSongYear != null) /*size=3*/ {
        mSongsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listSongYear);
        listView.setAdapter(mSongsAdapter);          

    }
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ali_slate.musicmvc.list.sortOutSongs">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sortoutsongslist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Comment: because make custom adapter then bind adapter into listview

Comment: and also used recycler view it latest and faster compare to listview

Comment: can you put your layout file here where list view is thr.....are you using any scrollview as a parent?

Comment: @SanatChandravanshi look

Comment: Please show the actual logcat error and add a [mcve] of your application

Comment: Sounds like you've written `Toast.makeText(listSongYear.size()` somewhere, which is incorrect

Comment: @cricket_007 you are genius, how did you know that i did that kind of mistake. butt i  have commented it after write this line of code

Comment: Because I've seen this error enough with beginners. I just use Log class. Toast should not be used as a debugging tool

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you String[] only contains non-null values as null values in the array will cause an exception